# Run TSQLScripts via the Web Page in c# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to build the Web Page which can be used to run the TSQL scripts online.

My DB has so many databases and I am using the System Administrator account to execute these scripts.

After building the web page,

1. I can run the simple CRUD statements successfully in all databases
2. I can run the DML statements only for the default connected database, which is MyDB1.
3. Whenever, I create the new Object, it sits in the MyDB1.  But I want to run / create objects in another DB.

I tried to run the following command, which is very simple and it works perfectly in SSMS.

```
USE MyDB2
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].MyProc

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.Table1
        (
        FieldA
        , FieldB
        , FieldC
        )
    VALUES
        (
        'AAA'
        , 'BBB'
        , 'CCC'
        )

END
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

My c# code to execute the posted script is here:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("MyConnString"))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            dt.Load(dr);
                        }

                        dr.Close();
                    }

                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log Error
            }
```

If I removed, USE statement, it was ok, but it created the object in the default DB which is MyDB1.  How I can tweak my code to run it in MyDB2?

Comment: Unrelated to the implementation please make sure you're not exposing this web page to the outside world.  This whole project reads like the obituary for an IT security professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USE` is an SSMS command, not a SQL statement.

Change your connect string to specify the appropriate database.

Comment: So is `GO`, by the way.